# Bockstein homomorphism and the universal coefficient theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, exact-sequence

The following statement is given in the third comment of
[*kernel of the mod  $2$  Bockstein on the first cohomology group*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233306/kernel-of-the-mod-2-bockstein-on-the-first-cohomology-group):

***Statement:*** Let $X$ be a path-connected finite $CW$-complex. Suppose 
$$
H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r}\oplus A
$$
where $r\geq 0$ and $A$ is a finite abelian group of odd order. 
Then for any nonzero element $x\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, $x^2\neq 0$.

**My attempt to prove the statement:**  I notice that for any nonzero element $x\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, $x^2=Sq^1 x=\beta x$ where $\beta$ is the Bockstein homomorphism associated with the coefficient sequence $$
0\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2\to 0.$$
Hence we only need to prove
$$
 \text{Ker} \beta=0.
$$
By the universal coefficient theorem,
$$
H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_4)=Hom(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{Z}_4) 
=Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r};\mathbb{Z}_4) 
=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r},$$

$$
H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=Hom(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{Z}_2) 
=Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r};\mathbb{Z}_2) 
=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r}.$$
By the construction of Bockstein homomorphism, we have an exact sequence
$$
H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_4)\overset{f}{\longrightarrow} H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)\overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow }H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}_2).$$

Hence when $r=0$, I obtain 
$$
\text{Ker}\beta=\text{Im} f=0. 
$$

Whether is my above argument right?

**Question:** When $r>0$, could we still obtain the statement, which is equivalent to prove that the image of $f$ is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $f$ isn't just any map: it's the map induced by the quotient map $q:\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ on coefficients.  By the naturality of the universal coefficients theorem (with respect to the coefficient group), the map $f:H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_4)\to H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ can be identified with the map $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}_4)\to\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}_2)$ given by taking a homomorphism $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Z}_4$ and composing it with $q$ to get a homomorphism $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Z}_2$.  But because $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2^r\oplus A$, the image of every homomorphism $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})\to\mathbb{Z}_4$ is contained in the kernel of $q$ (since every element not in the kernel of $q$ has order $4$, but $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})$ has no elements of order divisible by $4$).  So the map $\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}_4)\to\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is identically $0$.